# Migrate order billing profile

Tags: commerce, migrations, 9

I'm trying to migrate order data from an existing site using CSV files and I can't get the billing profile to relate.

In trying to troubleshoot this, I have it set just to insert a default value of a known profile and it's still not working for me. Currently, in the process section of my YML migration file I have these lines, but I still end up with `<null>` in the database.

```yaml
billing_profile/target_id:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 34338
```

I have also tried `billing_profile__target_id` and `billing_profile/0/target_id` instead of `billing_profile/target_id`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is it your exact yml definition? There seems alignment error. Try to align it properly.

Comment: Yml is highly indentation sensitive.

Comment: @miststudent2011 - That wasn't exactly spaced out like I had it, but I made some changes and now that is what I have. I think the problem is in addressing the property, but am unsure how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I'm new to using the Migrate system, so this may apply to anything with revisions like this, but apparently you MUST set both.

```
billing_profile/target_id:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 34338
billing_profile/target_revision_id:
  plugin: default_value
  default_value: 34338
```

Only setting `target_id` fails.